# display the footer always down the page always

Tags: css

I tried to stick the footer down the page and i failed, i googled many methods but no clue  .
Not fixed position , but to the end of the page , and if the content is little , it should visible down the page in that case ..

```
<body>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
  </div>  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <a class="logo" href="/">XP Blog</a>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      
          <ul class="right-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    <main class="main">


<a href="/posts/add" class="post-add"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
<h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
  
  <p>No posts yet</p>
  
</ul>

        </main>
    </div>
        <footer class="footer">
        <p>© 2020 XP Blog</p>  
        </footer>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        document.querySelector('.menu-btn').addEventListener('click', () => 
        document.querySelector('.main-menu').classList.toggle('show'));
    </script>
</body>


    * {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: 'Segoe UI', Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

a {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 85%;
  flex: 9;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.main-nav .logo {
  width: 100px;
  color: rgb(156, 4, 211);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #262626;
}

.main-nav ul.main-menu {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main {
  flex: 7;
}

.main h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

.post {
  margin: 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px rgb(162, 162, 162) solid;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}

.post:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.post-author {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.post-date {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: grey;
}

.post-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.post-add {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(202, 202, 202);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

input[type='submit'] {
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(1, 61, 1);
  color: white;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: #f2f2f2;
  color: #616161;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 20px auto 0;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  .main-nav .right-menu {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 60px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu.show {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu li {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
    line-height: 40px;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu li a:hover {
    margin-left: 2px;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

Comment: This may be helpful: https://css-tricks.com/couple-takes-sticky-footer/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add a `position: absolute;` to your footer, if you want it fixed or sticky.. add `position: fixed;` or `position: sticky;`

```css
* {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
  font-family: "Segoe UI", Tahoma, Geneva, Verdana, sans-serif;
  background-color: #fff;
  color: #000;
  font-size: 15px;
  line-height: 1.5;
}

body {
  min-height: 100vh;
  min-height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

html {
  height: -webkit-fill-available;
}

a {
  color: #262626;
  text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
}

.container {
}

.wrapper {
  width: 90%;
  max-width: 1100px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  min-height: 85%;
  flex: 9;
}

.main-nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: space-between;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 20px 0px;
  font-size: 13px;
}

.main-nav .logo {
  width: 100px;
  color: rgb(156, 4, 211);
  font-size: 20px;
}

.main-nav ul {
  display: flex;
}

.main-nav ul li {
  padding: 0 10px;
}

.main-nav ul li a {
  padding-bottom: 2px;
}

.main-nav ul li a:hover {
  border-bottom: 2px solid #262626;
}

.main-nav ul.main-menu {
  flex: 1;
  margin-left: 20px;
}

.menu-btn {
  position: absolute;
  top: 20px;
  right: 30px;
  display: none;
  z-index: 2;
}

.main {
  flex: 7;
}

.main h1 {
  border-bottom: solid 1px #f2f2f2;
}

.post {
  margin: 15px 0;
  border-bottom: 1px rgb(162, 162, 162) solid;
  padding: 10px;
  width: 90%;
}

.post:last-child {
  border: none;
}

.post-author {
  float: left;
  margin-right: 30px;
  font-size: 10px;
}

.post-date {
  font-size: 10px;
  font-style: italic;
  color: grey;
}

.post-content {
  margin-top: 10px;
}

.post-add {
  position: absolute;
  top: 70px;
  right: 30px;
  width: 50px;
  height: 25px;
  font-size: 20px;
}

form {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  width: 80%;
  margin: 20px;
}

input,
textarea {
  margin: 5px;
  padding: 5px;
  border: solid 1px rgb(202, 202, 202);
  border-radius: 5px;
}

textarea {
  height: 100px;
}

input[type="submit"] {
  cursor: pointer;
  align-self: flex-end;
  width: 100px;
  background-color: rgb(1, 61, 1);
  color: white;
  margin: 20px 30px;
}

.footer {
  background-color: rgb(199, 199, 199);
  color: #616161;
  font-size: 12px;
  padding: 20px 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  width: 100%;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  margin: auto;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 700px) {
  .menu-btn {
    display: block;
  }

  .main-nav .right-menu {
    margin-right: 50px;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu {
    position: absolute;
    left: 0px;
    top: 60px;
    background-color: #f2f2f2;
    width: 50%;
    border-right: #ccc 1px solid;
    opacity: 0.9;
    padding: 30px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 100vh;
    transform: translateX(-500px);
    transition: transform 0.3s ease-in-out;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu.show {
    transform: translateX(-20px);
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu li {
    height: 40px;
    border-bottom: #ccc 1px solid;
    line-height: 40px;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu li a:hover {
    margin-left: 2px;
    border-bottom: none;
  }

  .main-nav ul.main-menu li:last-child {
    border-bottom: none;
  }
}
```

```html
<body>
  <div class="menu-btn">
    <i class="fa fa-bars fa-2x"></i>
  </div>  
  <div class="container">
    <div class="wrapper">
      <nav class="main-nav">
        <a class="logo" href="/">XP Blog</a>
        <ul class="main-menu">
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/posts">Posts</a></li>
            <li><a href="/about">About</a></li>
            <li><a href="/contact">Contact</a></li>
          </ul>
      
          <ul class="right-menu">
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-user"></i></i></a>
            </li>
            <li>
              <a href="#"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
      </nav>
    <main class="main">


<a href="/posts/add" class="post-add"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></a>
<h1>Posts</h1>

<ul>
  
  <p>No posts yet</p>
  
</ul>


        </main>
    </div>
        <footer class="footer">
        <p>© 2020 XP Blog</p>  
        </footer>
    </div>
    
    <script>
        document.querySelector('.menu-btn').addEventListener('click', () => 
        document.querySelector('.main-menu').classList.toggle('show'));
    </script>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using `position: fixed;` and `bottom: 0;`

Something like this:

```
footer {
  position: fixed;
  bottom: 30px; /* adjust to what fits for you */
}
```

Here's the demo: https://jsfiddle.net/damagex/10qsLcg8/

Comment: Not what i need ... This will display the footer always .. i want it in the bottom of. the content but if the content is little , it should be down.